# FixedUpdate doesn't register all keys (unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I ordered a book and I've been following it's instructions fully. The only problem is when I put my movements in FixedUpdate it doesn't register every key. I've read many answers to this but they all say put your inputs in Update and put all of the physics in FixedUpdate. I did just that but when I press the spacebar 30 times it only jumps around 5. This is some of my code (I apologize if it's readability is bad, I'm just starting out.):

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject bullet;

    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public float rotateSpeed = 10f;
    public float jumpVelocity = 5f;
    public float distanceToGround = 0.1f;
    public float bulletSpeed = 100f;

    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    private float vInput;
    private float hInput;

    private Rigidbody _rb;
    private CapsuleCollider _col;

    private bool isShooting;
    private bool isJumping;

    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        _col = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();

        isShooting = false;
        isJumping = false;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        //player movement
        vInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
        hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotateSpeed;

        isJumping = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);

        //allows me to see if the spacer bar is registering
        if (isJumping)
        {
            Debug.Log("Jump");

        }

        isShooting = Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1);

        if (isShooting)
        {
            Debug.Log("Shoot");
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        Vector3 rotation = Vector3.up * hInput;
        Quaternion angleRot = Quaternion.Euler(rotation * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        _rb.MovePosition(this.transform.position + this.transform.forward * vInput * 
        Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        _rb.MoveRotation(_rb.rotation * angleRot);

        //determines if the player is on the ground and hit the spacebar. If so the player jumps.
        if (IsGrounded() && isJumping)
        {
            _rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpVelocity, ForceMode.Impulse);

        //this allows isJumping to revert back to false 100% of the time

            isJumping = false;

            Debug.Log("The jump mechanic is working");
        }

        if (isShooting)
        {
            GameObject newBullet = Instantiate(bullet, this.transform.position + new Vector3(1, 0, 0), 
            this.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            Rigidbody bulletRB = newBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            bulletRB.velocity = this.transform.forward * bulletSpeed;

            isShooting = false;
            Debug.Log("The shooting mechanic is working");
        }
    }


    //determines if the player is on the ground
    bool IsGrounded()
    {
        Vector3 capsuleBottom = new Vector3(_col.bounds.center.x, _col.bounds.min.y, 
        _col.bounds.center.z);
        bool grounded = Physics.CheckCapsule(_col.bounds.center, capsuleBottom, distanceToGround, 
        groundLayer, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);

        return grounded;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`FixedUpdate` is called once every 200ms or so depending on what you have the FixedUpdate interval set to.
`Update` is called once per frame.

`GetKeyDown` returns `true` on the *exact* frame you press the Key with the `KeyCode` you are targeting. On every other frame it returns `false`.

If you call `GetKeyDown` every frame in `Update`, `isJumping` will be `true` for the exact frame where you pressed the key, and **every other frame** it will be `false`.

Now imagine how that could affect the `FixedUpdate` method that **isn't called every frame**. `IsJumping` could be set to `true` and `false` before `FixedUpdate` is called even once.

You basically only want to set `IsJumping` to `true` in `Update` and then set it to `false` in `FixedUpdate`.

Your Update method should look like this in the end:

```cs
void Update()
{
    //player movement
    vInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed;
    hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotateSpeed;
    
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
        isJumping = true;
    }

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)){
        isShooting= true;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this what you meant (all of this is in the update but I couldn't figure out how to press enter without sending the comment).

Comment: Leave all your code as is. Just change the isJumping and isShooting lines to be exclusively set to TRUE in Update. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I didn't send my code I couldn't figure out how to. I tried commenting it but it all went to one line.

Comment: But then what does the FixedUpdate code look like? and in my if statement I also have jump calculations, so how does it know how high it should jump?

Comment: The code in the FixedUpdate method looks OK! As far as I can tell, you only need to change the code in the Update method to what I showed you.

Answer (score 0):

`Update` is called every frame.

`FixedUpdate` in certain time intervals but usually less often than `Update`.

`GetKeyDown` and `GetMouseButtonDown` are `true` only for exactly one frame, namely the one where the press began.

Instead of

```
isJumping = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space);
```

which resets the value to `false` already in the next frame - most probably before `FixedUpdate` is even called - you would rather want to do

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    isJumping = true;
}
```

and the same accordingly for `isShooting`